# Classification Accuracy with Temporal Component

Tags: classification, accuracy, spatio-temporal

### Problem

I have a 3D matrix of time-series, it's a spatial dataset with the 1st and 2nd dimension being x and y and the 3rd dimension being time. Some of the time-series have a structual break in them and some do not.

The task for an algorithm is to detect the breaks as soon as possible after they happen (online detection).

Now in general, getting the accuracy of the model without caring about the temporal component is trivial using precision and recall and calculating the F1 score. However choosing the model with the quickest response has me a bit stumped.

### Tried

In some publications they would get all the true positive, correctly detected breaks, and then calculate the distance of the delta-t (detected date minus true date) distribution to 0. With this however models with a really low precision could get very high scores, since only the true positives are looked at.

I was also thinking of linearly increasing the proportion counted as false positive the further the detection gets away from the true date. So if the break is detected with a lag of 0 days it will get counted 1 as a true positive and if it is for example detected 30 days late it will get counted as 0.5 true positive and 0.5 false positive. However this seems quite arbitrary to me, even though it might lead to results where the best performing model has a decent precision and quick detection.

Maybe some of you know of a way that is more robust (and maybe even published somewhere). It would help a lot